# Auto-Align Script misaligns on page load but not on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, centering

Hi please take a look at my site, the code snippet in question i have to center my images since ive never had any luck with the css-html methods. Sometimes it will load centered and sometimes it wont, please tell me how i can center my images on page load.

site: http://bit.ly/11nAQJK

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //Centering Script


$(document).ready(function () {
    updateContainer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateContainer();
    });
});


function updateContainer() {


(function ($) {
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var h = $(this).height();
    var oh = $(this).outerHeight();
    var mt = (h + (oh - h)) / 2;    
    $(this).css("margin-top", "-" + mt + "px"); 
    $(this).css("top", "50%");
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");    
    }); 
};
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
$.fn.hAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var w = $(this).width();
    var ow = $(this).outerWidth();  
    var ml = (w + (ow - w)) / 2;    
    $(this).css("margin-left", "-" + ml + "px");
    $(this).css("left", "50%");
    $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The point of StackOverflow is that it aims to be a Q&A community. Once you have an answer about your question, it is recommended to leave it for others to use as a base (wherever possible), not to delete it or replace it with gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have many variants. In your case you can do some like this

```
<div style="
  background: url('Assets/OrderSheet.png') center center no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
 ">
    <a href="Assets/OrderSheet.xls"> 
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: i tried this and it works, but how do i do this for the bitcoin button (that is actually a form)?

Comment: add this css to your imgs `#img{
   margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
}`

Comment: if you use this at the div,form etc. then you need to add a width option to your element. ie `#orderbutton > form { width:190px; margin: 0 auto; display:block;} #orderbutton{width:100%;}`

Comment: This doesnt scale down with the page, the image stays the same width.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use CSS over JavaScript for this, but that another story. To answer your question I think. pageLoad would be better than .ready

Comment: i tried that but it broke the script     $(window).load(function () {
    updateContainer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateContainer();
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$(document).ready()`, so the function is executed when the `DOM` is ready, but not necessarily all the images and such are loaded, so height and width info are not available yet, when you refresh the page, the info is available and you get the desired behavior.

To overcome this, use `$(window).load()`, so the function is executed when everything on the page is fully loaded, and info like width and height are available and you should get what you are expecting the first time the page is loaded.

Alternatively, if you need to keep using `$(document).ready()`, you need to specify the dimensions of the elements like the images explicitly so when the `DOM` is loaded the browser already knows the dimensions and doesn't have to wait for the elements like images to be fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but that broke the script! now all the images are left oriented.

Comment: As for the specifying the dimensions, how do i do it if they all have different dimensions?

Comment: Make sure it's $(window).load() not mistakenly $(document).load() (a common mistake). For dimensions you can assign ids to images and specify the sizes in your css or use inline image height and width, but inline size definition or styling is not recommended.